# I'm learning ASP.NET. Where can I find some (complete) sample website to study/analyse?

Tags: asp.net

I have learnt most of the main skill points in ASP.NET model, eg how to use a GridView. I would like to find some complete website with source code to analyse/observe, but so far it seems on the internet most learning resources are dealing with a specific topic. Is it possible to find some?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

There seems to be a lack of sample asp.net websites with available source code. Note an open-source website does not mean you can obtain the website. You may have to buy the website to view the open source. However I did find a large number of real-world websites with available source code in Chinese.

Comment: You never mentioned Chinese as a condition in your original question. If you want that then please insert that in your questions in the future.

Comment: @XIII It's obvious I want both English and Chinese, whichever is available but in English there are no commercial websites with available source code

Comment: @user370401: from your original question it's not obvious that you want Chinese as well. From your username or your profile it's also not obvious that you're focussing on the Chinese language market.

Comment: Oooh, lack of sample asp.net websites????? Were it the fact, what is the point in general abstract declarations? What are your findings? I dis not know that asp.net is already coded in Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of open source asp.net websites out there.

See [this](http://www.asp.net/community/projects) list from the Microsoft asp.net site, in particular the [starter kits and samples](http://www.asp.net/community/projects#jm_starter_kits_and_samples) section.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you download and install the free **[Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)** from Microsoft. In the tab **Web Applications** you can find a lot of ready made applications to learn from.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this video: http://www.asp.net/general/videos/build-your-first-asp-net-application-with-asp-net-web-forms

It explains well where to start and how to create "Hello World" type of application.

Don't bother with Web Platform Installer/other advanced starting kits because they are too complex for someone new with the platform.